# Accessing SQL database from Cocoa application

Tags: sql, cocoa

I want to connect a table that i have created in SQL Developer to the code i've written in XCode. This table basically contains the usernames and the associated passwords for the "would be" users of my application. I want to use this table to validate the user entry at the login page. Please guide me as to how the connection is to be made.
This is a small application i'm creating in an attempt to understand the cocoa concepts properly (alongwith the database).
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in Cocoa framework for accessing SQL databases.

If the database is in SQLite format, you may want to use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).